# datomic attribute with a colon prefix

Tags: datomic

Have 2 queries about datomic attributes.
1. If I know the attribute name (String), how do I check if the attribute is already defined or not in the schema?
2. Based on my experimenting with datomic, I see that datomic treats attributes with colon prefix and without colon prefix same. i.e if we create attributes named "foo" and ":foo", they are one and the same. Is this true? Is this a limitation?

I am using datomic with groovy.Below is the code used to create the attribute. Along with name, other params are input.

```
    static def createAttribute(String name, String type, String description, Connection connection) {
     List schema = [[
                    ':db/id': Peer.tempid(':db.part/db'),
                    ':db/ident' : name,
                    ':db/valueType': type,
                    ':db/cardinality': ':db.cardinality/one',
                    ':db/doc': description,
                    ':db.install/_attribute': ':db.part/db'
            ]]
            connection.transact(schema).get()
```

And the query I use to verify attribute presence is

```
    def attributeFor(String attributeName, Database db) {
     db.entity(attributeName).get(':db.install/_attribute')
    }
```

If I call "createAttribute" with "foo" as attribute name and "attributeFor" method ":foo" as attribute name, I get a result. i.e "foo" and ":foo" are treated same.
How can I create and query for attributes with name that contain a colon prefix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Datomic attribute names are not Strings, they are [edn keywords](https://github.com/edn-format/edn). The prefix colon is required (and always stored, regardless of whether you specify it in code.)  The optionality of the colon when working from languages that do not support a name literal (e.g. Java or Groovy) is intended as a convenience.